# jdbcTemplate does not work for new tables

Tags: java, spring, oracle

Something weird is happening with my SpringFramework web application (using Oracle xe backend). I can access all the old tables ok from jdbcTemplate, but if I add any new tables all queries return empty resultset without any errors. If I run a query from Oracle console as my spring database user, the query works fine.

Here is my test case:

1) Create the table

```
CREATE TABLE
TEST
(   "TEST" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE);

INSERT INTO TEST(TEST) VALUES ('Test');
```

2) Run a test from console (returns 'Test')

```
select TEST from TEST
```

3) Run a test from jdbcTemplate (returns 0):

```
System.out.println(jdbcTemplate.queryForList("select TEST from TEST", String.class).size());
```

Anyone experienced anything like this before? Any ideas what might be going on?

Regards,

Olli

Comment: Did you remember to commit the insert?

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thanks for pointing that out.